# redis-cli delete keys pattern not deleting records

Tags: redis

I have installed redis on my ubuntu server. I am traying to learn commands via `redis-cli`. I am seetnigs commands:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET book "read"
127.0.0.1:6379> GET book 
127.0.0.1:6379> DEL book
```

And I can list multiple keys like this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS "urn:products:*"
```

These commands work fine but I want to delete multiple records with pattern.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> DEL "urn:products:*"
127.0.0.1:6379> DEL KEYS "urn:products:*"
```

These commands not deleting records

Answer (score 1):

The `DEL` command doesn't accept a wildcard.  In your first example you're trying to delete a key named `urn:products:*` and in the second example you're trying to delete 2 keys named `KEYS` and `urn:products:*`.

If you want to delete a bunch of keys by a pattern you'll have to first run `KEYS` (or you should really be using `SCAN`) and then `DELETE` them in batches.

Answer (score 0):

As of the upcoming v3.4, you'll be able to use the [`PDEL`](http://redismodules.com/commands/pdel/) command from the [rxkeys module](http://redismodules.com/modules/rxkeys/). This variant the accepts POSIX Extended Regular Expressions.